# Transition from SQL server 2000 to SQL server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to move data using below script from SQL server 2000 to SQL server 2014 using Linked Servers. I'm having issues with below script. When I run below query on the new server not all the tables are updated. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

```
SELECT 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + '; INSERT INTO ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + 
' SELECT * FROM <TestServer>.<TestDB>.' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + ';' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "regularly"?  does that mean hourly/daily/monthly update?  or, near real time?    For encryption, you didn't specify your requirements.  encrypt data at rest?  in transit? etc.

Comment: @Greg-I mean update daily in the morning

Comment: There is still not enough information to help you.   Can you provide an example of an unexpected result that can be reproduced by others?

Comment: @TabAlleman - I've edited the question. Please let me know if you want me to add more details. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i have done in the past has worked well.

1. Create all of the tables in the new DB
2. Migrate all of the data, preferably during off hours so nothing is being changed
3. Create a link from 2K DB to new DB
4. Rename the tables in the 2k DB (Add _old, or something along those lines). This maintains an archive of the data in case anything got lost.
5. Create views in the 2k DB for each table and have the view point to the new DB

All reads, inserts and updates will go through the views of the 2K DB and end up in the new DB. All selects will come from the new DB. There is no need to ever do any data moves later, SQL is doing it all for you through the Views.

Then you can simply change the connections later.

Depending on the connection between the two servers this may add some lag, but it is a much easier migration.

Comment: Is there a need to create tables in the newDB? Can I just do a restore with a recent backup? Thanks for your response

Comment: You could but it is not so easy. this link has a good step by step for doing a restore from 2K to 2014. http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2014/sql-select-steps-migrate-sql-server-2000-sql-server-2014